# Create buttons and text boxes like Google Web Pages

Tags: jquery, css, jsp

How can I create the light weighted buttons and text boxes which was in google web pages like Google Search, Google plus and Google Play. I am using JSP and css.. I am ready to use jQuery.. Kindly do that needful. Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ bootstrap has some pre-made buttons that are nice. this question doesn't belong on stack overflow though, you can't just ask us for code without showing any effort on your part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see.. exapmle
http://purecss.io/
may be useful for u....

Comment: Please make an effort to write in proper english

Answer (score 0):

For creating a buttons like Google search you can use this code to create the different button.
**use this code as html code**

```
  <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="search text here" class="input-1" />
        <input type="submit" value=" OK " class="input-2" />
    </div>
```

**use this as css**

```
.input-1, .input-2{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.input-1{
    width: 70%; /* input-1 + input-2 = 100% */
}
.input-2{
    width: 30%; /* input-1 + input-2 = 100% */
}
.input-box{
    height: 32px; /* Own value - full height */
    width: 200px; /* Own value - full width */
}
```